# How to create a tuple with random numbers?

Tags: python, random, tuples

I want to create a tuple with n randomly generated real numbers. How can I do that? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: generate n random real numbers and store them in a tupple, how hard can it be?

Answer (score 5):

The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module offers functions for generating random numbers. We'll use [`random.random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random), which generates a number between 0 and 1.

To avoid the problems with trying to `append` to a tuple or modify its elements, we'll use the `tuple` constructor with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to build the tuple with random numbers already in it:

```
import random
nums = tuple(random.random() for _ in xrange(10))
```

If you're uncomfortable with generator expressions, this can also be done by building a list with a `for` loop and making a tuple out of it at the end:

```
import random
nums = []
for _ in xrange(10):
    nums.append(random.random())
nums = tuple(nums)
```